# Displaying Points and Lines in 3D

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

I'm trying to roll my own graph visualization, and to do that, I need a 3D plot of a graph.

I have the following code for generating points and edges:

```
vertices = Table[{RandomReal[], RandomReal[], RandomReal[]}, 20]
edges = Table[{RandomInteger[{1, Length[vertices]}], 
   RandomInteger[{1, Length[vertices]}]}, 40]
```

This here code runs just fine to display the points:

```
Graphics3D[
 Map[Point, vertices]
 ]
```

and this code generates a list of lines:

```
lines = Map[
  Function[e, Line[
    Part[vertices, Part[e, 1]],
    Part[vertices, Part[e, 2]]]],
  edges
  ]
```

My question now is this: How do I add the lines to the 3D graphic? I tried

```
Graphics3D[{
  Map[Point, vertices],
  lines
  }]
```

Comment: You need `Line[{pt1, pt2}]`, not `Line[pt1, pt2]`. Also, consider this: `Graphics3D[
 GraphicsComplex[vertices, {Point@Length@vertices, Line@edges}]]`.

Comment: Thanks, that worked.